# Not returning the array objects from database Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

This is the code from server side i have created but says :

```
[
  '60c65094d9e1242a18cf84da',
  '60c650d7d9e1242a18cf84db',
  '60c650fbd9e1242a18cf84dc'
]
```

*Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
at new ObjectID (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
at ObjectID (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:40:43)
at F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\index.js:49:36
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (F:\Web Development\Assignments\fresh-mart-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)*

```
app.post('/productsByKeys',(req,res)=> {
  console.log("found:ids",req.body)
  const productKeys = req.body;
productCollection.find({_id: {$in :ObjectID(productKeys)}})
  .toArray((err,items)=> {
      res.send(items);
      console.log(" found by ids: ",documents)
      console.log("RESPONSE :",err)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting you array into ObjectId(), convert individual items inside the array into ObjectIds.

```
const productKeys = req.body;
let convertedKeys = productKeys.map((x) => ObjectID(x));

productCollection.find({_id: {$in :convertedKeys}})
```

Comment: It works . Thanks for helping me Mr. "Tushar Shahi".